# Detect url change after # sign

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using this code to know what is in the url after # sign:

```
var a = document.URL.split("#")[1];
```

For example, if the url of page is `http://example.com/path/to/somewhere/#contentpart`, variable `a` will contains `contentpart`.

But the problem is, user may click on a link that points to same page but another part (for example: `<a href="#footer">Go to footer</a>`), and if so, page will **not** reload. (just page will be navigated to somewhere else)

My question is, how to detect when URL changes after # sign in the same page?

Any javascript/jQuery methods are welcome.

Comment: `window.location.hash` is not cool enough?

Comment: @webarto I didn't know that there is such thing available in javascript :)   Thanks!

Comment: @webarto: not everyone knows everything. That's what we're here for, to answer questions to help with learning. =)

Comment: @DavidThomas far from that, just reminded me of http://i.stack.imgur.com/TdrW7.gif :)

Comment: @webarto, ah, 'kay, I gotcha now; and yeah, I suppose that's something we're not, in some cases, sufficiently good at: showing that jQuery isn't always needed. =)

Comment: Ah come on, you replaced jQuery with Javascript, I'm a bad person now :) No offense to anyone, enjoy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest, bearing in mind your current code:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(e){
    var newHash = document.href.split('#')[1];
});
```

Though it's a little easier to simply use:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(e){
    var newHash = document.location.hash;
    console.log(newHash);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/FpU6J/3/).

If you don't want the hash to include the `#` character, then use instead:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(e){
    var newHash = document.location.hash.substring(1);
    console.log(newHash);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/FpU6J/2/).

Comment: Thanks, it worked! A question: `document.location.hash` returns `#contentpart` and not `contentpart`. How to remove that `#` from the result?

Comment: @MahdiGhiasi `.replace('#', '');`

Comment: @MahdiGhiasi: yeah, sorry, I was just getting to that, I'd suggest using `substring()` (as in the final code block), though `replace()` works of course.

Comment: Is there any difference between the performance of your suggested method and the method strangepants suggested (pure javascript)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but strangepants' approach uses the `document.location.hash` to assign the variable in the first place; whereas my answer shows how to use that approach, but I demonstrate it in response to the `hashchange` events (albeit using jQuery to do so). So, not really, I guess. I used jQuery to bind the events simply because it's easier than implementing my own shims and workarounds for older browsers (jQuery's already covered those bases for me, basically).

Answer (score 2):

You can get the URL hash by getting the `hash` property of  [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location)

```
var a = window.location.hash;
```

Changes to this property fire a [`hashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/hashchange) event in all modern browsers. There is a workaround for IE7 and below included in the MDN article.

```
window.onhashchange = function (e) {
    // Manage changes to your page
    // You can also inspect e.newURL and e.oldURL if you need to

    // Optionally prevent window from scrolling to target
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

If you're using jQuery, have a look at [jQuery BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/). It wraps up a lot of the quirks and browser compatibility issues, and also allows you to push changes to the URL / History state instead of relying on a user clicking a link.

Comment: Thanks for pure javascript method. as webarto said in comments, jQuery isn't everything! but, is there any difference between the performance of your suggested method and that jQuery method?

Comment: jQuery event binding always has more overhead compared to the native DOM methods ... but it's not worth worrying about: if you've already got jQuery on the page, just use it.

The jQuery methods also have one small additional benefit over my sample code in that using `on` allows you to bind and manage multiple event handlers.